# Wont click on this button with collapsible moves using Selenium with Java

Tags: java, selenium, button, xpath

I got this button:

[image]

It has this:

```
<strong data-bind="css: {'admin__collapsible-title': collapsible,
                      title: !collapsible,
                      '_changed': changed,
                      '_loading': loading,
                      '_error': error}" class="admin__collapsible-title">
            <span data-bind="i18n: label">Sales Matrix</span>
            <!-- ko if: collapsible --><span class="admin__page-nav-item-messages">
                <span class="admin__page-nav-item-message _changed">
                    <span class="admin__page-nav-item-message-icon"></span>
                    <span class="admin__page-nav-item-message-tooltip" data-bind="i18n: 'Changes have been made to this section that have not been saved.'">Changes have been made to this section that have not been saved.</span>
                </span>
                <span class="admin__page-nav-item-message _error">
                    <span class="admin__page-nav-item-message-icon"></span>
                    <span class="admin__page-nav-item-message-tooltip" data-bind="i18n: 'This tab contains invalid data. Please resolve this before saving.'">This tab contains invalid data. Please resolve this before saving.</span>
                </span>
                <span class="admin__page-nav-item-message-loader">
                    <span class="spinner">
                       <!-- ko repeat: 8 --><span data-repeat-index="0"></span><span data-repeat-index="1"></span><span data-repeat-index="2"></span><span data-repeat-index="3"></span><span data-repeat-index="4"></span><span data-repeat-index="5"></span><span data-repeat-index="6"></span><span data-repeat-index="7"></span><!-- /ko -->
                    </span>
               </span>
            </span><!-- /ko -->
        </strong>
```

It's XPATH is:

```
//*[@id="container"]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/strong
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"container\"]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/strong")).click();
```

but it says it couldnt found something with "strong".

Also, i tried this:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sales Matrix")).click();
```

But it wont work.

---

I solved it by doing this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Sales Matrix')]"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: Are you sure it is not under any ifreame?

Comment: Hey @KunduK hmm, i don't really know. Just want to click on that button that contains other things. What would you do to solve this?

Comment: @KunduK i'm kinda lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the below `xpath`

```
//span[contains(text(),'Sales Matrix')]
```

***OR***

```
//span[normalize-space()='Sales Matrix']
```

***OR***

you can use `elementToBeClickable(..)` this will judge the element visible and enabled, so you can click on it.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)); 
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("above-expath")));
element.click();
```

***import***

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait
```

Comment: Hi, how are you?. You mean this: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Sales Matrix')]")).click(); ?

Comment: Hey, Yes, try with both `xpath` as i did not tested in my machine.

Comment: I tried both XPATH, take a look:
a) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Sales Matrix')]")).click();
b) driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[normalize-space()='Sales Matrix']")).click();.
Did not work

Comment: What `error` are you getting ?

Comment: Take a look: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[normalize-space()='Sales Matrix']"}

Comment: If i try to use your third method i got this error message on the IDE: "The constructor WebDriverWait(WebDriver, int) is undefined"

Comment: Hmm, it is strange. I do not know what to do

Comment: Have you added the import ?

Comment: Yeah, i use this instead: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));  but it says the same. Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //span[contains(text(),'Sales Matrix')] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)

Comment: Can you provide the `url` ?

Comment: The problem is it is not exposed at all. Can i give you something different instead?

Comment: I get it, it's the locator issue I think, so can you provide the `url`  if possible or check the HTML is there any frame ?

Comment: I can give the HTML DOM?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248565/discussion-between-akzy-and-programming-amazing).

Comment: Hey pal, i was able to solve it by using this:  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Sales Matrix')]"));
 JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);;